# MongoDB unable to run in Windows7

Tags: mongodb

we have installed MongoDB 3.2.1. When i try to run it shows the following error.

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongo.exe
>   2016-01-13T12:48:14.974+0530 I CONTROL  Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is installed, no need to zero-out data files
>   MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4
>   connecting to: test
>   2016-01-13T12:48:15.996+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be
>    made because the target machine actively refused it.
>   2016-01-13T12:48:16.002+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attemp
>   t failed
>       at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
>       at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
>   exception: connect failed

Please any one help us to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you verified that mongo service is up and running?

Comment: Am not able to run the mongo i tried the steps as shown video 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sReI0-QnDJk' .  But am getting the following error.2016-01-14T10:39:57.748+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28663 Cannot start server. The defau
lt storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine exp
licitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating.please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Your OS is x86 or x64?

WiredTiger
MongoDB 3.0 introduces support for the WiredTiger storage engine. With the support for WiredTiger, MongoDB now supports two storage engines:

MMAPv1, the storage engine available in previous versions of MongoDB and the default storage engine for MongoDB 3.0, and
WiredTiger, available only in the 64-bit versions of MongoDB 3.0.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0/